# compactly generated spaces

Tags: general-topology, compactness

A topological space $X$ is called compactly generated if following condition holds:

$A\subseteq X$ is open in $X$ iff for every compact $K\subseteq X$, $A\cap K$ is open in $K$.

My lecturer said that a topological space $X$ is called compactly generated if following condition holds:

$A\subseteq X$ is open in $X$ iff for every compact $K$ and continuous map $f: K\rightarrow X, f^{-1}(A)$ is open in $K$.

the necessary condition is clear. To prove the sufficient, I bit confuse. I think if  $f: K\rightarrow X$ is continuous and $f^{-1}(A)$ is open in $K$, obviously that $A$ is open in $X$. Hence we no need condition $X$ to be a compactly generated.

Please tell me if it is not true.

Comment: Note that , the formal statements  stats that if $f$ is continuous and  A is open , then $f^{-1}(A)$ is open,thus if  $f^{-1}(A)$  is open and $f$ is continuous this does not imply that A is open.

Answer (score 0):

The definitions are equivalent because, for a set $A\subseteq X$, the intersection $A\cap K$ is open in $K$ for every compact set $K\subseteq X$ if and only if $f^{-1}(A)$ is open in $L$ for every map $f$ from a compact space $L$ to $X$.

For one direction you need the fact that the image of a compact space under a continuous map is compact. For the other direction try to express the intersection $A\cap K$ as the preimage under some map $i:K\to X$.

Comment: I did not understand your answer. For one direction is obvious. But for another direction is not clear.

Comment: @lili: Could you say which direction is unclear?

Comment: if $f^{-1}$ is open in $K$ ...... then $A$ is open in $X$. Should $K$ compact subset of $X$?

Comment: @lili: So assume $f^{-1}(A)$ is open in $K$ for every map $f:K\to X$ from a compact space $K$. Now if $K\subseteq X$ is compact, the inclusion $i:K\to X, x\mapsto x$ is such a map, so by assumption, $i^{-1}(A)=A\cap K$ is open in $K$.

Comment: I know it. But I am thinking whether $K$ is any compact space (it no need to be subset of $X$), does $A$ still open in $X$?

Comment: @lili: The wording in my answer was a bit unfortunate, so I changed it. I'm still not sure which direction is troubling you. Let's say $\mathcal P$ is the property 
$$\text{$A\cap K$ is open in $K$ for every compact $K$ in $X$.}$$
and property $\cal Q$ is
$$\text{$f^{-1}(A)$ is open in $K$ for every map $f$ from a compact space $K$ to $X$.}$$
Then is it $\cal P\to Q$ or $\cal Q\to P$ which is troubling you?

Comment: If $K$ is being compact subset of $X$, I can understand your proof. My problem is that I thought $K$ no need to be subset of $X$. So, I thought the theorema states as follows: Let $X$ be compactly generated. Then $A\cap K$ is open in $K$ for every compact subset $K$ of $X$ iff $f^{-1}(A)$ is open in $K$ for $f:C\rightarrow X$ is continuous for any compact space $C$.

Comment: @lili: In $\cal P$, $K$ ranges over the compact subsets of $X$, while in property $\cal Q$, $K$ can be any compact space. Since for any $A\subseteq X$, properties $\cal P$ and $\cal Q$ are equivalent, it doesn't matter if we define a compactly generated space as a space where $A$ is open if it satisfies $\cal P$, or as a space where $A$ is open if it satisfies $\cal Q$.